# Плавное включение светодиода на stm32f103

Tags: stm32, микроконтроллеры

Всем привет. Нужна ваша помощь. Нужно разработать программу для плавного включения и выключения светодиода с помощью двух кнопок и ШИМ таймера TIM1 на stm32f103. Как это сделать - не понятно.

Comment: На самом деле, светодиод выключается полностью. Просто из-за высокой частоты не видно паузы между вспышками светодиода. Яркость меняется из-за изменения напряжения, и как следствия тока

Answer (score 1):

Настройки таймера:

```
void TIM_initial (void) //Аппаратный таймер PWM
    {
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;
    RCC-> APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;

    //Выход PWM **********************
    GPIO_INIT_PIN(GPIOA, 1,     GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT10_ALT_PUSH_PULL); // Tim2_ch2 Яркость LED

    TIM2->PSC=72-1;  //18-1;  //Предделитель
    TIM2->ARR = 100-1; //Делитель, определяет период выходного сигнала (с учетом предделителя будет 10/40kHz)

    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE;//Включен режим предварительной записи регистра автоперезагрузки
    TIM2->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC2PE;//Включен режим предварительной загрузки регистра сравнения  

    TIM2->CCMR1 |= (TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_2 | TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_1);//OC2M = 110 - PWM mode 1

    TIM2->CCR2 = 50; //Длительность импульса (по отношению к arr). В данном случае Duty cycle = 50%

    TIM2->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC2E;    //Выход канала захвата/сравнения включен
    TIM2->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1P;        //Полярность выходного сигнала
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;               //Старт счета таймера
    }
```

Яркость регулируется изменением значения регистра TIM2->CCR2.

Answer (score 0):

Яркость светодиода в данном случае зависит от коэффициента заполнения ШИМ. То есть при частом включении и выключении светодиода светодиод не отключается полностью, а немного затухает. То есть ваша программа должна для плавного включения светодиода постепенно увеличивать коэффициент заполнения, для плавного выключения - постепенно уменьшать.

Comment: На самом деле он всё таки тухнет. Просто особенность человечячего зрения такова, что мы не успеваем этого заметить, а наш мозг раскладывает это на яркость.